# kubernetes - ConfigMap mount into single file

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, kustomize

I'm trying to mount a file using configmap during kubernetes deployment.
I have my application properties as data in my configmap. I'm creating configmap using `kustomize`. Kustomize will help to merge two configmaps. When I build `kustomize` it returns configmap like

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  append.properties: |
    TEST_PROPERTY_1=5
  base.properties: |
    TEST_PROPERTY_2=test
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-configmap
```

When I mount this config map it will create two different files. But I want to merge into a single file. my application server will expect a single property file. Can someone help this problem?

Comment: Does it have to be a file? You can pass them to environment variables?

Comment: @suren My application server will expect it as file. and I have 100+ properties

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a startup script to merge these two files into one property file when the pod startup.

Answer (score 0):

I think [config mixin documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/combineConfigs.md#create-and-use-the-overlay-for-development) is what you are looking for. You are probably just missing the

```
behavior: merge
```

in the configMapGenerator of your overlay.